# Don't send modify event to inotifywait if file is opened

Tags: linux, rsync, windows-subsystem-for-linux, inotify

I use VSC as an editor on Windows 10 Pro and want to sync to a remote server on file change.

I installed WSL with a debian guest system

If I run this script

```
while inotifywait -r -e modify,create,delete /path/to/folder; do
  rsync -rltzv --progress --chmod=0600 --exclude=.git/ --exclude=.vscode /path/to/folder user@example.com:~/remote/folder;
done;
```

The rsync is started not only, when I save a file in VSC, but also, when I open it. While this is not critical, it is annoying and a wast of bandwidth.

Can I do anything against it?

### Edit

I don't know, what coused this, but the problem doesn't seem to happen any more on my machine with my setting. But I didn't change anything

Comment: This could be caused by the creation of a lock file or a backup copy or some local logging, so not really an "open" event (for which there is a specific filter in inotifywait). With the proper `rsync` option there shouldn't be much bandwidth wasted anyway. Since you use Git a better option would be to use a Git hook  to update the server when you commit.

Comment: @xenoid There is no lock file or anything like that. `inotifywait` exactly tells me which event of what file is registered and it the `MODIFY` event of the just opened file.

Comment: @xenoid What would be these proper rsync options?

Comment: @xenoid I cannot use git to do this, as I need the sync on file change, not on commit

Answer (score 0):

You are monitoring too many events[*]. The events that matter are:

- `CLOSE_WRITE`, because putting data in files requires to close them. You can also consider that the file is in a consistent state at that point.
- `DELETE`, for files that are removed
- `MOVED_TO`, `MOVED_FROM` for files that are added to the tree, moved out of it, or just renamed.

[*] For instance, experimentally, `MODIFY` happens many times (probably for each write operation on the file) and copying the file at that point could copy a file in an inconsistent state. Likewise, `OPEN` occurs even if you don't make any changes later.

Comment: From [`inotifywait`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) man page: `close_write: A watched file or a file within a watched directory was closed, after being opened in writeable mode.  This does not necessarily imply the file was written to.`

Comment: This will not work (at least not in WSL). The saving of a file doesn't dispatch any of those events you listed. Only `modify` does

Comment: Strange, works with my editor (kate) and other Linux utilities (touch, piping...). The problem with MODIFY is that you don't know if this is the final edit. Did you try `inotifywait -m` and can you add the complete sequence of received events to your question (not using -m may makes you miss events while inotifywait is restarted)?

Comment: Strange is, the problem doesn't occur any more on my machine